# What is the difference between the time complexities of vector <int> a {N, 0} and int arr a[N] = {0}

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, time-complexity, difference

What is the difference between the time complexities of `vector <int> a {N, 0}` and `int arr a[N] = {0}`, when initializing them with a fixed variable?

If they both are same then what techniques can we use to decrease time complexity in our program when initializing arrays?

Comment: Also how vector <int> a (N, 0) works while initialization.

Comment: What have you attempted so far to answer your question? Have you run and timed code? If so, what did you find? If not, do it **before** asking a  question here. Note also that `int arr[N]={0}` requires `N` to be a constant expression (to be standard compliant), while `vector<int> a{N,0}` does not. So you're comparing apples with oranges: if `N` is a compile-time expression, and smallish (<1000), then the array, avoiding heap-memory allocation, should be faster.

Comment: Time complexity is not the same thing as speed. There should be no difference in initalisation time here. The two key differences between a vector and an array is that with a vector, you can allocate/reserve a block of memory upfront and not actually construct objects on that memory until it's needed (important for arrays of large objects). The other difference is the `vector` will use a dynamic allocator, which is slower than automatic allocation and incurs a potentially massive penalty if it's single threaded in a multi-threaded program.

Comment: The time complexity will be the same but the `int arr[N]` will be faster if it is placed on the stack because stack allocation is essentially free. I would think that everything else should run at similar (if not the same) speed.

Answer (score 0):

The vector data is allocated on the heap and the array on the stack. Other than that hopefully you compiler will optimise both to a single `memset(0)`.

To know the exact timing you will need to benchmark this yourself on your compiler. I doubt that this will take a significant amount of time though, the rest of your program is likely to be slower.

Write your program first, see if its fast enough. If it isn't then profile it and concentrate on the slow bits. Making small optimisations like this before you even know whether they are needed is often fruitless.

Comment: Reminder:  `memset` works on the byte level.  Multibyte integers may not be set the same way using `memset`.  The `std::fill` function would be better.  Your mention assumes that setting all bytes of a multi-byte integer to zero will set the  integer to zero.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Why wouldn't setting all bytes of an integer to zero result in setting an integer to zero? I wasn't suggesting using memset anyway, just that was hopefully what the compiler would do in the background, most implementations of memset are optimised to use SIMD instructions for maximum performance.

Answer (score 0):

Vector allocates memory in the heap hence it is little expensive to allocate memory for vector since heap data structure need to search for available block of memory in heap. In case of array, memory is allocated in stack which is equivalent reducing stack pointer. However both vector and array initializing almost takes same time, since both of the use `memset` and then mapped to [stos](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/X86-assembly/Instructions/stos) hardware instruction. Main difference is in allocating memory. When I was developing a high performance software, I did find that allocating and initializing vector was taking significant time (depends on the size).

Time complexity of initialization is same for vector and array. Allocating is vector far more expensive than vector.